# Unable to populate custom azure B2C attribute via azure function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have been trying to Create a Custom policy that on sign-in it calls an an azure function and then populates a custom attribute.

I have been following this guide https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Azure-AD-B2C-Series-External-Service-Call/

This is my trustframeworkextension.xml

```
  <ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure-Functions-Get-External-System-Id-On-Registration</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Azure-Functions-Get-External-System-Id-On-Registration">
      <DisplayName>Get external system ID for the user on registration</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">
        https://azureb2ccreatecrmcontact.azurewebsites.net/api/CreateCrmContact?code=app-function-code
        </Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
      </InputClaims>
     <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_external_system_id" PartnerClaimType="external_system_id" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Azure-Functions-Get-External-System-Id-On-Registration" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

this is the return value of my function. I can confirm via the monitor that it is getting fired during signup but it is not populating the custom attribute.
This what my function is returning according to the monitor logs

```
 {"extension_external_system_id":"c87f6324-012d-ea11-a810-000d3a7940d5"}
```

I can only see the default value being populated in my jwt response token

```
"extension_external_system_id": "external_system_id_1234"
```

Any push in the right direction would be a blessing. Thanks.

My function code

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("CreateCrmContact")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        var email = data?.email;
        var firstName = data?.given_name;
        var lastName = data?.family_name;
        Guid contactId = new Guid();
        if (email == null || email == String.Empty)
        {
            new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass user email in the request body");
        }
        log.LogInformation($"Email : {email}");
        log.LogInformation($"Firstname : {firstName}");
        log.LogInformation($"Surname : {lastName}");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("FirstName", (string)firstName);
            dict.Add("LastName", (string)lastName);
            dict.Add("Email", (string)email);
            var formEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(String.Format("apiuri"), formEncoded);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse<MemberCreateResponse>>(result);
            log.LogInformation($"Contact created with id: {deserializedResponse.ResponseData.ContactId}");
            contactId = deserializedResponse.ResponseData.ContactId;
        }
        var sysInfo = new ExternalSystemInfo
        {
            external_system_id = contactId.ToString()
        };
        var serializedObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sysInfo);
        log.LogInformation($"GetExternalSystemIdOnRegistration got external system id for user: {serializedObj}");
        return new OkObjectResult(sysInfo);
    }
}
class ExternalSystemInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("external_system_id")]
    public string external_system_id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you completely follow this article, the name of the returned parameter has to be exactly set to: "external_system_id". In the AD B2C custom policy we will set it as a “PartnerClaimType” and policy will expect response parameter with such name.

Now check your Azure AD B2C custom policy:

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_external_system_id" PartnerClaimType="extension_external_system_id" />
</OutputClaims>
```

You should set the value of PartnerClaimType as "external_system_id" rather than "extension_external_system_id".

Comment: Hi Allen. Thanks for the comment. This is what i originally tried, however it didn't work. In light of your comment i have just tried again and it still doesnt return the expected value. I have updated my code in the original post to reflect the changes. I also added my azure function code.